# Excel file corrupt while uploading using Spring Boot + Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upload an excel file using angular js + spring boot. The file gets uploaded successfully, but the file seems to be corrupted. I can not open the file. Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<p align="right">
    <input type = "file" id="file" name="file"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
</p>
```

**controller.js**

```
function uploadFile() {

        var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.log(file);

        var uploadUrl = "/uploadAsExcel";

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('uploadfile', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })

        .success(function(){
        })

        .error(function(){
        });
    }
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAsExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile uploadfile) {

    try {
        // Get the filename and build the local file path
        String filename = uploadfile.getOriginalFilename();
        String contentType = uploadfile.getContentType();
        System.out.println("ContentType: "+contentType);
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\user122\\Documents\\MyFiles\\"+filename;

        //Save the file locally
        BufferedOutputStream stream =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath)));
        stream.write(uploadfile.getBytes());
        stream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    //resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return resolver;
}
```

The Excel file upload is successful, but when I open the file, it says "the file is corrupted". Basically, I need to read the excel file using Excel API and do some operations.

Can you please anybody help here ?

Thanks,
Karthik